# Using search from other site on yours

Tags: php, jquery, html, search, forms

I want to put a search form on my site, but when you hit search, it will search another site.

For example, I have a form on mydomain.com/search that will search domain.com/search?term="keyword"

Once I hit the search button, I want it to open a new window appending the keyword to the URL.

Can this done via jQuery/PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need javascript or jQuery to do this.  Just use normal HTML.

```
<form action="http://www.domain.com/search" method="GET" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with HTML.

```
<form action="http://example.com/search" target="_blank">
```

The usual issues with new windows apply.